# Passing Multiple Values to Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am still new to ASP.NET and am having issues passing multiple values to my stored procedure. I have a grid view and the parameter is pulling from a checkboxlist. The parameter is for year. So, what I would like to do is have it select the parameter as '2007,2008,2009' and then I would parse it out within the stored procedure.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="spr_playerStats" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:string %>" SelectCommand="spr_playerStats" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" DataSourceMode="DataReader">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cbl_season" Name="season" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>



    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbl_season" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">2007</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">2008</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">2009</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating based on the comment below:

You can add following code in your code behind to achieve that:

```
var spParams = String.Empty;
foreach(ListItem lstItem in cbl_season.Items) 
{
    if(lstItem.Selected)
    {
        if(spParams != String.Empty)
            spParams += ",";

        spParams += lstItem.Value;
    }
}
spr_playerStats.SelectParameters["season"].DefaultValue = spParams;
```

Comment: I have that function. The problem is getting the value from the checkboxlist into that comma-separated format.

Comment: I have added the code. I am new to .NET, so I am just using the GUI. I do have a lot of SQL experience, so I am good once I get the values in the format I want.

Comment: Do you want to pass it to spr_playerStats SP?

Comment: Yes. I want the website to pass the value to the stored procedure spr_playerStats as '2007,2008,2009'

Comment: I just updated the answer. I just tested and it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44069/discussion-between-adarsh-shah-and-neil)